# Need to set RichTextBox ZoomFactor twice?

Tags: .net, winforms, richtextbox

I noticed that the `ZoomFactor` of my `RichTextBox` Control is reset to `1.0` when calling `Clear()`.

My first attempt to save and restore `ZoomFactor` failed. I have to set it to `1.0` and then a second time to get an effect.

```
  private void ClearOutputWindow()
  {
        RichTextBox rtb = textBox2;

        //  save zoomfactor to restore it later
        var zSave = rtb.ZoomFactor;

        rtb.Clear();

        //  we have to set it to 1.0 first
        //  and then to the desired value 
        //  otherwise it won't work ...
        rtb.ZoomFactor = 1.0f;
        rtb.ZoomFactor = zSave;
  }
```

Is there any reasoning behind this behaviour under `.NET Framework 4.7.2`?

Comment: Yes, the RichTextBox wrapper class is not aware that Clear() also resets the zoom factor.  It avoids updating the native control when it doesn't see a change in the value, so re-assigning has no effect.  The workaround you found is the correct one.

Comment: The *mistake* is in the [ZoomFactor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,1577) Setter. You can see the Getter send `EM_GETZOOM`, then calculate the Zoom factor. The Setter instead only relies on the internal Field current value. This is not correct, since the Control's Text is changed by P/Invoking `SetWindowText()` in the Control class, which knows nothing about *zooming*. So, the zoom value can and will be changed *elsewhere*. The Setter should get the *live* Zoom factor from the RichEdit control.