# Listen to RichTextBox.ZoomFactor has changed event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I cannot determine why the ZoomFactor of my Winforms RichTextBox is getting reset to 1.

I checked all calls to `Clear()` and when setting the `Text` property and I am aware of the *Set-ZoomFactor-twice*-bug ([Need to set RichTextBox ZoomFactor twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929389/need-to-set-richtextbox-zoomfactor-twice)).

Now I wonder whether there is a way to debug into some *ZoomFactor-has-changed*-event in order to determine why and how the ZoomFactor is changed automatically.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**Edit 1**

I can reproduce the reset as follows (at least in my application):

- Click into empty RichTextBox
- Increase zoom using Ctrl and mouse wheel
- Click somewhere else
- Click into the RichtTextBox again

This suggests that the ZoomFactor is automatically reset if the Text property is empty and the RichTextBox becomes focused, not just when calling `Clear()`. Could this be the reason?

**Edit 2**

I could *not* reproduce the effect using a new Winforms example project and the above procedure. This means, I have to look for some side effects in my application.

**Edit 3**

The ZoomFactor has been reset due to an overlooked `Text = <empty string>`. It is working now.

Comment: There is no event for that property.  You could use Debug > New Breakpoint > Function Breakpoint and type "System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.set_ZoomFactor".  But of course that won't break if the effective zoom factor gets changed by something else, like Clear().

Comment: Thanks, Hans! I just tried it, but it only breaks when I set the ZoomFactor programmatically. The automatic ZoomFactor reset is not captured. Interestingly, changing the ZoomFactor by scrolling with the Ctrl key pressed is also not captured!